# toUpperCase() in getAttributeNode

Tags: javascript

How to make it workable that img src is gonna change to PIC_BULBOFF.GIF?

```
<img class="dd" src="pic_bulboff.gif" >

<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dd")[0];
    x.getAttributeNode("src").value = ///x.toUpperCase///;
</script>
```

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dd")[0];var attrib=x.getAttributeNode("src");attrib.value=attrib.value.toUpperCase();
`  you could of course also use `setAttribute` & `getAttribute`

Answer (score 3):

Use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` to *set* and *get* value of an Element's attribute respectively.

```
x.setAttribute("src", x.getAttribute( "src" ).toUpperCase() );
```

**Demo**

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dd")[0];
x.setAttribute("src", x.getAttribute( "src" ).toUpperCase() );
```

```html
<img class="dd" src="pic_bulboff.gif" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
alert(x.getAttributeNode("src").value.toUpperCase());
```